# is there an ownerof function equivalent for ERC1155?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, erc-1155

I would like to be able to call all the addresses for a specific tokenId in an ERC1155 contract in order to airdrop those with a specific token.
I know ERC721 has the function ownerof to allow for this, is there an equivalent for ERC1155?

Answer (score 2):

There is no function for this on `ERC1155`.

Because a token is **not necessarily unique,** it can have **multiple owners**.

Same as `ERC20` there is no function to list all the holders.

On ERC1155 `_balances` mapping is like this:

```
mapping(uint256 => mapping(address => uint256)) private _balances;
```

Simple representation:

```
TokenID => holder => amountOfTokenID
```

For one `TokenID` you can have multiple holders

To answer your question: It is not possible to retrieve this information from the smart contract.

However, it is possible to get this information off-chain using `events` with the right logic / filters

Or via TheGraph.

Comment: The mapping you mentioned is available in the ERC1155 standard?

Comment: yes it is taken from Openzeppelin